# Listagem de dados de formulários - Django

Tags: formulário, django-templates

Boa noite! Tenho um formulário de avaliação criado no Django 2.0.4, no qual são inseridas 3 perguntas juntamente com suas respostas, porém, ao listar o resultado em uma página só é listada a última pergunta e resposta. [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Clique em **[edit]** e adicione seu código.

Comment: Qual método você está usando para ler do modelo?